# Migrate UWP project from VS 2015 to VS 2022 and from windows 8.1 to windows 10

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2022, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I have a UWP project for win 8.1 in visual studio 2015, I want to make a migration so that I can work in Visual Studio 2022 and upgrade from win 8.1 to win 10,
The project in VS 2015 looks like this:
[image]

From what I read VS 2022 can't open windows 8.1 projects. I have two questions: Can I open this project in visual studio 2022? and if so how I made the migration? because right now the project in vs 2022 is "incompatible".

I'm pretty new in developing UWP so I don't know exactly what I need to add in this description, If you need to add more details I will be happy to do so.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is that there is no such tool that could do the migration automatically. You have to do the migration work manually. And please try to use VS 2017 to open your windows 8.1 project (VS 2019 might be able to open windows 8.1 project as well).

You have two options when you begin the porting process. One is to edit a copy of your existing project files, including the app package manifest. Here are the documents: [Migrate apps to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/misc/migrate-apps-to-the-universal-windows-platform-uwp?view=vs-2015&preserve-view=true).

The other option is to create a new Windows 10 project in Visual Studio and copy your files into it. Here are the documents: [Porting a Windows Runtime 8.x project to a UWP project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-porting-to-a-uwp-project).